# OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database in ubuntu server

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu, flask, mod-wsgi

I'm running a FlaskApp using `mod_wsgi` and `apache2` on Ubuntu server. I tried running the flask app on `localhost` successfully and then deployed it on ubuntu server.

But when i try to update database, its giving error:

```
Failed to update model. (OperationalError) attempt to write a readonly database u'UPDATE mysongs SET songurl=? WHERE songid.id = ?' (u'www.site.com/I_wanna_dance', 1)
```

Now i tried look for database file permission which is:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 10240 Jul 14 15:35 /var/www/mywebsite/appfolder/appdata.db`
```

When i try changing permission to 777, 755, 644 etc. it shows another error: `unable to open database file` Although database file works fine with 644 permission on `localhost` but not on ubuntu server.

Also i checked permission of directories and for `/var` `/var/www` `/var/www/mywebsite` `/var/www/mywebsite/appfolder` etc., all have `www-data:www-data` as its owner username and group.

I tried googling and but no proper solution other than suggestion of changing file/dir permissions, which i have tried myself.

Why can't it read/access the database file?

Please suggest.

Comment: Did you use uid (http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#uid) and gid (http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#gid) for run uwsgi. Which user start uwsgi?

Comment: Are you using an absolute path to the database file? Under mod_wsgi the current working directory will not be where you think it should be and relative paths will fail. By rights if this is what you are doing, then it will not even find a database file, but worth checking. Also confirm the web application processes are in fact running as www-data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved the issue. It was due to database file permission conflict.

Comment: Could you update your question with your solution so people searching SO in the future can see what you did?

Comment: Fix: You need to find database file in your system and give access to write. (for example git access to all: sudo chmod a+w file.db)

Comment: You need to give www-data permission to your project and db, see my answer.

Comment: This answer could be useful if you'd add precise explanations on the resolution

Comment: This answer contains no detail. Please consider adding the details of your solution.

Answer (score 9):

This issue is related to the files permissions management AND mostly to the user chosen in the Apache configuration file (`*.conf`) defined to holds the application processes. In a few words : the **write permissions** need to match this user.

Most of the time, the sqlite database file has been created by a specific user (for example your current user) and the site application is running under child processes launched by the Apache default user **www-data** (if the parameter `user` wasn't specified inside the directive `WSGIDaemonProcess`). In this case, the database can be read but it will throw this error if you try to modify anything :

> (OperationalError) attempt to write a readonly database...

because *www-data* has no permission on the file (or on the parent folder)

---

**First way : Apply permissions to the user www-data**

You can set the *write* permissions on the database file and its parent folder.

If the folder contains other files, you can add write permission on it and only change the ownership of the database file to the user *www-data*, for example :

```
sudo chmod o+w db_directory
sudo chown www-data:  db_directory/site_database.db
```

Or if the folder contains only the database file, you can try to change the folder owner directly :

```
sudo chown -R www-data: db_directory
```

Then check that *read*/*write* permissions are well set (with `ls -l site_database.db`)

More help in [this post.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6723/change-folder-permissions-and-ownership)

---

**Other solution : Add a specific user to hold the application processes**

This can be done by giving the [`user` and `group` parameters](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIDaemonProcess.html) in the directive `WSGIDaemonProcess` in Apache configuration. 
It will make Apache launch the child processes under a specific user.

For example :

```
...
WSGIDaemonProcess main user=myuser group=myuser threads=3 python-home=/path/to/the/virtualenv/
WSGIProcessGroup main
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
...
```

This user will manage all operation, including read/write to any files, so check that it has all needed permissions on every related files.

For security concerns, you may not use a wide-privileged user.

Some comments can help in [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/294101/wsgidaemonprocess-specifying-a-user).

---

**Note** : be careful if you manage your own logging files with directives like `ErrorLog` in the Apache configuration, these files will follow the same logic of permissions. The same for any file that could be changed by the application.

Comment: For SQLite you would also need to have the directory the database is in writable to the user the code runs under, else it can't create the database lock file. So changing ownership of the database file is not enough.

Comment: I've run this methodology, but it still does not work. what could I be going wrong? the db folder permissions show up as `drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data`. I've also run 666 permissions on the db file itself, and it shows this:

`getfacl users.db

# file: users.db
# owner: www-data
# group: www-data
user::rw-
group::rw-
other::rw-`

Comment: The specific user solution and link were helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Just give www-data permision to your project and db

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data ProjectPath

sudo chown www-data:www-data dbPath
```

Comment: Worked thanks.

I was working on aws ec2 instance and same error poped up. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score -1):

Faced this issue while hosting Django Rest Framework on IIS 7.5 / Windows 2008 Server. It was working fine on local host . I added new feature to handle file upload feature along with "file name" . The files were uploaded properly but the database seemed to not accept the text from "file name" string.

**Solution :**
Go to your concern database. (if you have not assigned any particular database,consider the file *db.sqlite3* in base folder)

Right click on the **db.sqlite3 --> Properties --> Security --> Edit --> Add**

In the text box enter **Everyone --> Checkname --> ok**

Refresh the server at IIS and try to run the application.

Comment: This question isn't for Windows. It's for Ubuntu.