# Django admin backend 'Operational Error' attempt to write a readonly database

Tags: python, django, nginx, sqlite, gunicorn

This question seems to have been asked many times but all the solutions I have checked haven't yet worked for me. I am running `nginx` on a Ubuntu 14.04 server with Django 1.6.1 installed. I am attempting to use the default django admin backend for a project (usually at localhost/admin/).

The issue I run into is `OperationalError at /admin/ attempt to write a readonly database`

(Update when I changed chmod permissions for the db.sqlite3 file the error now reads `OperationalError at /admin/ unable to open database file`  but I have checked every option on the [Django Newbie Mistakes](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/NewbieMistakes#DjangosaysUnabletoOpenDatabaseFilewhenusingSQLite3) website for the answer and no dice)

Some answers talked about the r+w+x permissions for the generated database file `db.sqlite3` as far as I can tell even `777` on the db file doesn't do anything so I've kept it at `656`.

As far as I can tell the django project works find (all pages render fine, the /admin page renders without css. When i attempt to login using localhost/admin/ and click submit I get the django debug page with the error). They are all owned by `root:root`. I have tried changing permissions for every file and directory to be owned by `www-data:www-data` but nothing.

I have even tried changing the settings.py to have an absolute path to the db instead of `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3')`

I think its down to an ownership problem but I'll take any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After all that hassle and 2+ hours of banging my head against a wall, the answer for the archives...

I was using gunicorn, I took a cookie cutter set up from Digital Ocean which made the user django. I thought it the cookie cutter approach would be a shortcut which was easy to modify and skipped the boring bits. It turns out in `/etc/init/gunicorn.conf` `setuid` and `setgid` was set to the user django. My fault for not reading the documentation and assuming these meant little.

If you are having this problem either delete `setuid` or `setgid` or set them to `www-data`.

Comment: I had a very similar problem which was fixed by the solution I found in the comments here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17641993/operationalerror-attempt-to-write-a-readonly-database-in-ubuntu-server simply `chmod a+w db.sqlite3`

Answer (score 0):

This error usually caused by running the server as a different user (i guess you are running a linux machine). If you have created the project as a root/administrator and running the server as a user with lower status, then you will get the error.

try running the server with sudo permission, i.e

```
sudo python3 manage.py runserver
```